# PHPMailer hangs on mail send

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I try to send an email to a user, but once `$mail->send()` is being executed, nothing happens and the web page just got stuck and hangs on for 5 minutes.

This is the `$mail` setup:

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

class Email {
  private $mail;

  function __construct() {
    $config = parse_ini_file(__DIR__ . '/../../private/config.ini');
    $this->mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $this->mail->IsSMTP();
    $this->mail->SMTPDebug = 4;   
    $this->mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $this->mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
    $this->mail->Secure = 'ssl';
    $this->mail->Host = $config['smtphost'];
    $this->mail->Port = 465;
    $this->mail->Username = $config['smtpusername'];
    $this->mail->Password = $config['smtppassword'];
  }
}
```

After 5 minutes, this message shows up in the browser:

```
2020-04-01 22:53:58 Connection: opening to ##mysmtphost##:465, timeout=300, options=array()
2020-04-01 22:53:58 Connection: opened
```

I've examined any similar problem and its solutions, but none of those seems to be helpful for my problem.

The sending:

```
$mail = new Email();
$mail->AddAddress($_POST['forgot_password']['email'], $foundEmail['username']);
$fromEmailAddress = ###MyHostEmailAddress###;
$fromName = ###name...###;
$mail->SetFrom($fromEmailAddress, $fromName);
$subject = ###subject..###;
$msgBody = $url;
$mail->Subject($subject);
$mail->Body($msgBody);
if($mail->Send())
  $validationMessage = 'TEST'
```

Comment: *"I try to send an email to a user, but once $mail->send() is being executed, nothing happens"* - Where's that code and how are you using all of this?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner edited.

Comment: This timeout suggests that access to your mail server is blocked, or the mail server is down - it's not your script's fault. As the PHPMailer docs mention, synchronous sending via remote SMTP is fundamentally unsuited to use during page submission. Use a local mail server as a relay, or reconfigure your script to use a mail server provided by your host that is not subject to blocking (e.g. as GoDaddy requires).

Comment: @Synchro The mail server does working. I tested it via SMTP Online Tool (SMTPer.net) and I did get the mail successfuly. But when trying to send the mail in code, I don't get the email.

Comment: That a mail server is accessible from *outside* a network is entirely unrelated to whether it's accessible from *inside*. For example, I can access gmail's servers from home just fine, but I would not be able to from within GoDaddy's networks. Test using the advice given in the troubleshooting guide to diagnose this properly.

Answer (score -2):

Try to return something after the send function because i think (so I'm not sure 100% but i had such problem) the phpmailer when calling the send function use threads so it send the mail using a thread so if ur code ends or die without return the thread will be also stoped or died. Also u can dump the result of the send() if it's true that's mean that ur configuration is ok else that mean that u have a problem with it